# Trying to print contents of a vector: having trouble with "No operator "<<" matches these operands, operand types are: const char [2] << Card" error

Tags: c++, vector

My program is a simple card game. The 'Deck' class is where I am getting the error. I have looked at countless other question to solve it but I just can't. I have already included , and the relevant header files. A few other solutions were way beyond my understanding and said something about using "std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Course& course)", but I have no idea what this is or how to use it. (I'm new to C++). All I'm trying to do is output the contents of a vector. I would really appreciate some help with this.

```
#include "Deck.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

Deck::Deck()
{
}

void Deck::shuffle()
{
}

void Deck::setDeck(vector<Card> targetDeck)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < deck.size(); i++)
        targetDeck.push_back(deck[i]);


    // vector<Card> populatedDeck(targetDeck);
}

void Deck::getDeck()
{
}


int Deck::printDeck(vector<Card> cards)
{
    std::cout << "Vector contains: ";
    for (vector<Card>::iterator it = cards.begin(); it != cards.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << (" " << *it);
    }

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The compiler doesn't know how to output a `Card`.  You have to write the code to tell it this information by providing an overloaded `operator <<`.

Comment: You need to implement a `operator<<` for a `Card`. Without it the compiler has no idea how to print that type. It can't just magically guess how you want any arbitrary type to be printed.

Comment: `cout << (" " << *it)` This is problematic

Comment: What resource are you using to learn C++? This will be covered in most books. At least I assume it would. It's called operator overloading.